# Ubuntu 22.04 integrated intel graphics with fullscreen virtualbox guests

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, virtualbox, fullscreen

I have just reinstalled my HP ZBook with a discrete nvidia card and integrated Intel graphics to vanilla 22.04. The guest additions are installed and work fine. Everything was working fine with 20.04.

Now on 22.04 when I launch a virtualbox guest in fullscreen when the Intel graphics card is active then I lose the mouse and typically the screen goes black. Both Win11 and Ubuntu 22.04 guests are the same. When not in full screen they both work fine. When I activate the NVidia card (and reboot) everything works fine.

Other things (VLC, etc.) work fine and look great in fullscreen with both drivers.

I have tried all possible options virtualbox offers on the Diplay side (all the virtual graphics controllers, with/without 3D, increasing the VRAM, etc.)

I have updated to the latest virtualbox (including guest additions) using the virtualbox package repo. Still no dice.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mention Window and Ubuntu guests. Which host OS?

Comment: @ChanganAuto, sorry, I thought that would be clear from the title.

Comment: No, the title has a veil suggestion but can be interpreted many ways, not clear at all. Thank you for editing.

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but guest additions belong in the virtualbox *guest* OSes, not the *host* OS installed on the hardware.

Comment: Thanks @Esther, I wouldn't be getting fullscreen when the NVidia card is active if guest additions weren't properly installed.

Comment: I saw some suggestions to increase the amount of VRAM allotted to the VMs